# Div doesn't slide down on first click, but slides right after

Tags: jquery, image, function, onclick, slidedown

I have a set of thumbnails that represent my work. Once you click on a image the row of thumbnails slides down to reveal a slideshow and information up top. I'm having a problem that it abruptly shows the information instead of doing the slideDown effect on the first click. But after the first click it displays the slideDown effect.

[My website](http://www.xerxesjarquin.com)

Heres the javascript code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#thumbs li a, #full-thumbs li a').on('click', function(e){
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#inside').slideUp(400,function(){
          $('#inside').load(href).slideDown(400,'swing');
          $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top }, 400);
            $.getScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');
            $.getScript('js/retina.js');
            $.getScript('js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', function () {
              $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                pager: false,
                auto: true,
                autoHover: true,
                mode: 'horizontal',
                touchEnabled: true
              });
            });
        });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why including jQuery again?

This line should not be there

```
 $.getScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');
```

Comment: Ooops! I thought you needed to bring up jquery again, so that the slideshow could work.